# Upgrade paypal SDK from 2.11.2 to 2.12.0 iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal

How to upgrade the paypal SDK of existing project to the latest SDK . I have used cocoa pods to install the SDK  to my project. Not able to upgrade it .

Here is the link of the github

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove paypal pods form your pod file  and add the new pod form paypal github page
and the hit pod install on your terminal.
it will install the latest libray in your project.

you may have to change something on code for payment.